# Why does intitle:1 show questions whose titles don't have all my search terms?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

This a follow up on [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39332/searching-using-intitle). Why doesn't intitle:1 show questions which have my search terms in the title only. Filter out questions which do not have all the words in the title.

Example: intitle:1 cookie static (or intitle:1 +cookie +static)

Why is it displaying questions which do not have both words in the title? Is there a boolean format I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the terms in quotes for an exact match

> intitle:1 "cookie" "static"

edit: I added an alias for this.

> intitle:1 +cookie +static

now works as well

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle%3A1+%2Bcookie+%2Bstatic

Comment: i get why `foo bar` and `"foo bar"` are different, but why is `foo` different from `"foo"`??  nonintuitive!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37825/what-is-a-bad-feature-of-stack-overflow/37877#37877

Comment: The help on search needs to be more complete.

Comment: @tony I updated it

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The query should be [`title:cookie title:static`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Acookie+title%3Astatic) instead of `intitle:1 "cookie" "static"`.