# Searching for words in question titles

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to search for questions that have specific words in their titles using the [`intitle`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39370/177227) search feature, but it seems that it does not return any search results.

Using this feature, I tried to search for questions on Stack Overflow with ["prolog" in their titles](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intitle%3A1+prolog), but this search query returns no results.

Is it still possible to filter the search results based on words in question titles?

Comment: the parameter is `title` not `intitle` see [this result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aprolog&mixed=1)

Comment: Can the close voter please clarify why they believe this question is no longer reproducible?

Answer (score 12):

That answer from Jeff you linked to is obsolete.

From the Advanced Search [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

> - to limit your search to just the title of a question, use `title:` followed by the search term. Likewise, search the body only (exclude the title) with `body:"phrase here"`.

So for your specific search you would do

> [`title:prolog`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aprolog&mixed=1)

which returns all questions with the word "prolog" in their title.

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52956/177227) is also obsolete, so it also needs to be updated.